# How to update database from dynamically created webpage? PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a part of webpage that is dynamically generated using MySQL queries:

```
<table id="livePlayers" cellpadding="4" align="center">
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Phone number</th>
<th>Email Address</th>
<th>Rating</th>
</tr>
<?php
  while ($currLine = @mysql_fetch_array($resultSet))
  {
    $phoneCount= "phone".$count;
    $ratingCount= "rate".$count;
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $currLine[1]?></td>
<td><?php echo $currLine[2]?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $phoneCount ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $currLine[0]?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $ratingCount ?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php
    $count++;
  }
?>

</table>
```

As you can see, 2 fields are of `input type="text"`. Once the user has made entries in these fields, I need to update the database table with these values on clicking Submit.

However, I don't understand how to do this since the field `name` would be dynamically generated. Is there any way to update the respective rows with entered values?

Comment: `name` should be static, you should store the value in `value` attibute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` of an input should not be generated dynamically. Instead use a constant. The dynamic value of that input should be set in the `value` attribute of the input.

Example for one of your inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phoneCount ?>" />
```

You can retrieve the value by using the $_GET or $_POST arrays. Assuming your form uses the POST method you can do the following:

```
$phone = $_POST['phone']; // the entered text for the phone field
```

Now you can write your UPDATE mysql query.

## Update

To update more than one row at the same time, use an array as POST parameter:

```
<input type="text" name="phone[]" value="<?php echo $phoneCount ?>" />
```

Retrieving `$_POST['phone']` will give you an array of all rows then.

## Update 2

To identify each row you can use hidden fields like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
```

Or you use the id as associative array key for all other input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="phone[<?php echo $id ?>]" value="<?php echo $phoneCount ?>" />
```

Comment: The last part is what my actual question is. If there are 100 rows in the table and each rows has `<input type="text">`, how do I update for all 100 rows using a single `Submit` button? Or I would need a Submit button for each row? That would be a dirty fix to update all rows

Comment: You can use an array as POST parameter. See my updated answer.

Comment: Another question, the updates would obviously need a primary key from the page, in this case the Email address field. Considering that the table is dynamically generated with 100 rows of the type

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a form for the page to submit the user changes back to the PHP, and make your PHP page accept a form input (POST), then parse that input, and use that data to update your database.

Answer (score 3):

@darkie

As you've to retrieve all the records from a table and need to update them, you might have to use a loop for every record to update using PHP.

How to get the values?

- Use a counter, and give names to the input fields like 'phone1' and 'rating1' and so on
- Enclose all the <input> with form tag.
- use OnSubmit() action, and retrieve all the values and create a matching string through JS or JQuery.
  Eg: phone1:123  rank1:1 phone2:456 rank2:2 , Make a string like : 123::1|456::2 etc
- Send the string to your PHP backend - Split the string and start the loop
- With your primary key, use UPDATE to update them.

P.S :- I believe you should have echoed phoneCount and ratingCoung in the "value" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Note: `name` should be static, you should store the value in `value` attribute, otherwise how did u get the value of that input fields??

otherwise there is alternative is
use
USE `extract($_POST)` so that you will get associative array with key of `name` field and value of `value` field

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice to use dynamic names. That being said; it can be done.

I would **prefix** the names with "Phone_"

```
<input type="text" name="Phone_<?php echo $phoneCount ?>">
```

You can now loop all the Post-variables and pick out everyone that starts with "Phone_"

You loop like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
     print "$name : $value<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What would be the best way to achieve the same without using dynamic names?